# ngFor duplicando valores ao mudar e voltar de página

Tags: angular, ionic

Fiz uma api que gera apenas um valor, já no aplicativo que utilizo Ionic e Angular. Ao entrar na página Principal o valor único aparece lá, mas quando eu vou a uma página secundária e nela clico no "Voltar", o valor único é duplicado / carrega outro de novo.

**component.ts**:

```
loadDaymm(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let body = {
            aksi : 'd5d519f0b2abb86766aada568eb50d61',
            limit : this.limit,
            start : this.start,
        };

        this.postPvdr.postData(body, 'api.php').subscribe(data => {
            for(let day_rmmdata of data.result){
                this.day_rmmdatas.push(day_rmmdata);
            }
            resolve(true);
        });
    });
  }
```

**page.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let day_rmmdata of day_rmmdatas">

    <div class="header">
        <div class="title">{{day_rmmdata.title}}</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está nessa linha:

```
this.day_rmmdatas.push(day_rmmdata);
```

Na primeira vez que você entra na página, o array `this.day_rmmdatas` está vazio. No entanto, na segunda vez que você volta na página, o array já está com o valor que você obteve na primeira vez. Uma possível solução é sempre zerar o array antes de fazer a requisição:

```
loadDaymm(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let body = {
            aksi : 'd5d519f0b2abb86766aada568eb50d61',
            limit : this.limit,
            start : this.start,
        };

        this.day_rmmdatas = [];
        this.postPvdr.postData(body, 'api.php').subscribe(data => {
            for(let day_rmmdata of data.result){
                this.day_rmmdatas.push(day_rmmdata);
            }
            resolve(true);
        });
    });
  }
```